# Conditional menu in WordPress via functions.php (no plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

In `WordPress`, I want to display a different menu on the front page than on all other pages (without plugin). I'm using a theme I created myself.

This is the code:

**`functions.php`**

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Main navigation', 'theme' ),
        'menu-2' => esc_html__( 'Sub Menu', 'theme' ),
        'menu-3' => esc_html__( 'Footer - Navigation', 'theme' ),
    )
);

function theme_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

    if( is_front_page() ) { 
        $args['menu-1'] = 'Main navigation - front page';
    } else { 
        $args['menu-1'] = 'Main navigation - sub page';
    } 
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'theme_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

**`header.php`** (dynamically loaded into all pages)

```
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            )
        );
    ?>
```

The strange thing is, this code worked on `localhost`. After uploading it to the server and a series of changes in the `WordPress` dashboard, it stopped working.

I tried to recreate the process, but without success. So now I'm wondering, is some thing incorrect in my code? What am  I missing?

**EDIT:**

I tried different suggestions (thank you all, so far!).

If I put this in my `HTML`, WordPress will always use the footer navigation as main navigation, even though in the dashboard, footer is clearly set as such - and only such:

```
        if( is_front_page() ) { 
            wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'menu-1','menu_id'=>'primary-menu'));
            } else { 
            wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'menu-2','menu_id'=>'primary-menu'));
        }
```

I find that weird, because in `functions.php`, footer is `menu-3`. But this code doesn't mention `menu-3` anywhere.

By using this in my `HTML`, the main navigation shows as main navigation and footer only as footer:

```
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            )
        );
```

I tried vicky's suggestion for my `functions.php`, but I keep having the same issue that the same main menu is used for front page and other pages...

Comment: all dashboard changes are you made it in server correctly? like set the home page in settings page?

Comment: In page settings, home page and blog page are set. I set them again and saved it to make sure, but no changes. In the menu settings, ` 'Main navigation - sub page' ` is set as standard, same as on localhost. If I set ` 'Main navigation - front page'` as standard, it applies it to the sub pages as well. On localhost, it used `'Main navigation - front page'` for the front page, due to my if-statement (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the filter hook wp_nav_menu_args from your functions.php and put the below code in your header.php

```
if( is_front_page() ) { 
   wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'menu-1','menu_id'=>'primary-menu'));
} else { 
   wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'menu-2','menu_id'=>'primary-menu'));
}
```

Comment: I did that. In the WP dashboard page settings, I set `Main navigation` as menu for the front page and `Sub Menu` for all other pages. But now for some reason it will always use the footer navigation as main navigation, even though the footer navigation is clearly set as such. `menu-3` only appears in the code for my footer and in the dashboard, it is defined as footer navigation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Main navigation', 'theme' ),
        'menu-2' => esc_html__( 'Sub Menu', 'theme' ),
        'menu-3' => esc_html__( 'Footer - Navigation', 'theme' ),
    )
);

function theme_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

    if( is_front_page() ) { 
        $args['menu_id'] = 'Main navigation - front page';
    } else { 
        $args['menu_id'] = 'Main navigation - sub page';
    } 
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'theme_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions above, I've edited my code. It's now working! :) Thanks everyone!

(note that names are slightly different in this version since I changed those as well once it was working)

The working code in `functions.php`

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Navigation 1', 'theme' ),
        'menu-2' => esc_html__( 'Navigation 2', 'theme' ),
        'menu-3' => esc_html__( 'Fußleiste - Navigation', 'theme' ),
    )
);

function praxis_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
 
    if( is_front_page() ) { 
        $args['menu-1'] = 'Startseite';
    } else { 
        $args['menu-2'] = 'Unterseiten';
    } 
        return $args;
    }
```

And in `header.php`:

```
        if( is_front_page() ) { 
            wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu-1','menu_id'=>'primary-menu'));
         } else { 
            wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu-2','menu_id'=>'primary-menu'));
         }
```